# have modified /usr/include/c++/4.9 files by mistake

Tags: g++

because of the modifications i Am getting so many errors while compiling any c++ files

how can i restore it.please help

Now while compiling any program it is giving

try.cpp:1:19: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include
                   ^

Answer (score 1):

Find the package that owns the files with `dpkg -S /usr/include/c++/4.9`, then reinstall it with `sudo apt install --reinstall package-name-you-got`.